# How to compile source objects into another directory and then build an executable?

Tags: makefile, directory, compilation

Good day. I am in a directory, where is Makefile and folders src and bin. How can I compile object files into bin folder and then build an executable file?

I read some instructions and added $(BIN) before %.o, but it didn't helped, object files appear in folder with makefile. Where is the problem?

```
CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
CXX = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
CPPFLAGS = -I .
CFLAGS =-g -std=gnu99 -O1 -Wall
CXXFLAGS = -g -std=gnu++11 -O1 -Wall
LDFLAGS = -lrt -lpthread
SRCDIR = src
BIN = bin
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)*
...
OBJECTS += $(filter %.o,$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o))
OBJECTS += $(filter %.o,$(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o))
#$(warning OBJECTS=$(OBJECTS))
ifeq ($(filter %.cpp,$(SOURCES)),)
LINKER = $(CC)
LDFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
else
LINKER = $(CXX)
LDFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
endif
$(BIN)/%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
$(BIN)/%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
all: $(TARGET_EXE)
$(TARGET_EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -L. $^ -o $@
.PHONY : dep all run copy-executable debug
dep: depend
depend: $(SOURCES) *.h
    echo '# autogenerat`enter code here`ed dependencies' > depend
ifneq ($(filter %.c,$(SOURCES)),)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -w -E -M $(filter %.c,$(SOURCES)) \
      >> depend
endif
ifneq ($(filter %.cpp,$(SOURCES)),)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -w -E -M $(filter %.cpp,$(SOURCES)) \
      >> depend
endif
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET_EXE) connect.gdb depend
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how this makefile can works as well as it does, given that you haven't told it where to find the source files (unless you do so in one of the elided sections).

In these rules:

```
$(BIN)/%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
$(BIN)/%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

you tell the compiler to build object files, but you don't specify *where* to build them, and the default is to build them in the working directory. You can override that with the [-o option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options):

```
$(BIN)/%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(BIN)/%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Once you have the object files where you want them (`bin/`), you must ensure that the linking rule:

```
$(TARGET_EXE):$(OBJECTS)
    $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -L. $^ -o $@
```

can find them. The best way to do that is to ensure that `OBJECTS` contains the correct paths to the object files. I'm not sure how to advise you to do that, since from the look of your makefile that variable might not contain what you think it does.

**EDIT:**

Let's take this in stages.
Suppose we have on source file, `src/foo.c`. What we want is:

```
src/foo.c -> bin/foo.o
bin/foo.o   -> foo
```

This requires two rules, which we can write like this:

```
$(BIN)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET_EXE): bin/foo.o
    $(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -L. $^ -o $@
```

We actually have many source files, some of which are C++ files. So we must have a rule for them:

```
$(BIN)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

and construct a longer list of objects:

```
OBJECTS := bin/foo.o bin/bar.o bin/baz.o bin/quartz.o...
$(TARGET_EXE): $(OBJECTS)
$(LINKER) $(LDFLAGS) -L. $^ -o $@
```

(Mixing C and C++ seems unhealthy to me, but never mind.)

And how do we construct that list of objects? We must start with the list of sources which `wildcard` can produce:

```
SRC := src
C_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC/*.c)
# this is src/foo.c src/bar.c

SRC := src
CPP_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC/*.cpp)
# this is src/baz.cpp src/quartz.cpp
```

and then convert them to the object file names we actually want:

```
BIN := bin
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.cpp,$(BIN)/%.o, $(CPP_SOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(BIN)/%.o, $(C_SOURCES))
# this is bin/foo.o bin/bar.o bin/baz.o bin/quartz.o
```

That should give you the effect you want, and if you understand it you will understan why your old makefile did not.

Comment: SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c) tells Makefile where are source file, doesn't it?

This Makefile makes all object files into src folder, all is correct, but I want it to make object files into bin